# Is Use Proxy Integration option in API Gateway supported in Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am using API Gateway and want to automate the creation of my environment using Cloudformation.

I'm only missing one thing, the `Use Proxy Integration` option. I can't find a reference to it in the documentation.

Here's an image of what I am talking about:

[image]

Is this available in Cloudformation and if not, any ETA or plans to make it available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer to my question:

The Type, in the Integration , must be set to HTTP_PROXY and not HTTP.

```
Method:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
    Integration:
    Type: HTTP_PROXY # can also be: AWS, AWS_PROXY, HTTP, HTTP_PROXY, MOCK
```

Answer (score 1):

`HTTP_PROXY` is correct for HTTP Endpoint pass through. If you are looking for Lambda Pass Through Proxy, you have to use `AWS_PROXY`.

Adding some description on each type.

- **AWS** : for integrating the API method request with an AWS service
  action, including the Lambda function-invoking action. With the
  Lambda function-invoking action, this is referred to as the Lambda
  custom integration. With any other AWS service action, this is known
  as AWS integration.
- **AWS_PROXY** : for integrating the API method request with the Lambda
  function-invoking action with the client request passed through
  as-is. This integration is also referred to as the Lambda proxy
  integration.
- **HTTP** : for integrating the API method request with an HTTP endpoint,
  including a private HTTP endpoint within a VPC. This integration is
  also referred to as the HTTP custom integration.
- **HTTP_PROXY** : for integrating the API method request with an HTTP
  endpoint, including a private HTTP endpoint within a VPC, with the
  client request passed through as-is. This is also referred to as the
  HTTP proxy integration.
- **MOCK** : for integrating the API method request with API Gateway as a
  "loop-back" endpoint without invoking any backend.